# Installed Habitat, Unicorn.aspx missing

Tags: unicorn, habitat

I've got the Habitat source for `Sitecore 9.1` from https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/tree/master

I was a bit surprised that `Unicorn.aspx` was missing from the code. I was thinking it should be part of the `Sitecore.Foundation.Serialisation project`. The default gulp script includes a step for `Sync-Unicorn` which is obviously failing.

I tried upgrading the Unicorn NuGet project in `Sitecore.Foundation.Serialisation` but this didn't add Unicorn.aspx

What am I missing?

Comment: No file actually exists. If all the proper configurations are there then the url is available.

Comment: What Michael said. Unicorn.aspx is a url catch mechanism, not an actual file anywhere. If sync is failing it will be due to mis-configuration, not missing files.

Answer (score 0):

Mike is correct, No file actually exits and if configurations are correct then URL is available. If you are facing issue any issue in `unicorn sync` then the most common problem is incorrect source folder path in `Habitat.Dev.config` file. In Sitecore 9 Habitat you will find it at - `src\Project\Habitat\code\App_Config\Environment\Project\`
Also, make sure your root hostname is correct in the same file. `sourceFolder` tells Unicorn where your serialization yml files are.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore>
        <sc.variable name="sourceFolder" value="C:\projects\Habitat\src" />
        <sites role:require="Standalone">
            <site name="habitat">
                <patch:attribute name="database">master</patch:attribute>
            </site>
        </sites>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its an issue with Unicorn sync - with current Habiat solution and Sitecore  9.1 Update-1 as as Sitecore 9.1 uses identity server for authorization .
Basically Unicorn needs to be updated to V4.0.7 in project: Sitecore.Foundation.Serialization
I too faced this issues and penned down all details here - https://blogsaurabhrajpoot.com/2019/07/21/habitat-on-sitecore-9-1-unicorn-sync-not-working/

Please let me know if it works.